# What are the possible list of Linux bash shell injection commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, code-injection

We are writing a Linux bash shell script that receives arguments. We wanted to fail the script when it receives possible shell injections commands as parameters. I have added some commands below using regex. Can someone give me possible list of all such commands so that we can avoid threats

```
invalid_format="(^.*[;&|].*$)|(\brmdir\b)|(\bls\b)|(rm\s-)|(\bping\b)"

if [[ $LOCAL_DIR =~ $invalid_format ]]; then

echo "Error! LOCAL_DIR cannot contain command chaining characters like ; && || or possible shell injection commands"

exit 1
```

Comment: There is no limit to the list. Don't try to filter out things that are known to be bad; accept only things that are known to be good.

Comment: You'll want to read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: Even better, handle the data correctly so it can't do damage even if it *does* include shell syntax.

Comment: ...forgetting to quote isn't really the problem here -- the problem is getting content into a context where it'll be `eval`ed. The fix is to **never** substitute **any** data into a string that will be evaluated as code, but only pass that data out-of-band from the code itself.

Comment: You might also find value in bash's `printf "%q"` format

Comment: Also note that if your shell script is invoked from a non-shell language, much of the critical work is how you write the code in that non-shell language; once the script is invoked, it's too late to do anything there (if its parameter list was unsafely substituted into a shell generating a command line).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Don't Use Blocklists.

A blocklist of content that is explicitly disallowed in your data is just an invitation for someone to come up with a vulnerability that isn't on it, or to obfuscate their code so a regex can't match it, or to find an oddball syntax honored by your *actual* shell but not by the one the blocklist/validator was written for.

Don't fight that losing battle; instead, write code that's safe *no matter what content your data contains*, by never injecting data in a context where it could be evaluated and executed as code.

---

## Using Arguments In Shell Scripts Safely

- **This is inherently unsafe:**

  ```
  eval "grep -e \"$1\" /var/log/*"         ## DO NOT EVER DO THIS
  eval "grep -e '$1' /var/log/*"           ## DO NOT EVER DO THIS EITHER
  sh -c "grep -e \"$1\" /var/log/*"        ## DO NOT EVER DO THIS EITHER
  sh -c "grep -e '$1' /var/log/*"          ## DO NOT EVER DO THIS EITHER
  ssh somehost "grep -e \"$1\" /var/log/*" ## DO NOT EVER DO THIS EITHER
  ssh somehost "grep -e '$1' /var/log/*"   ## DO NOT EVER DO THIS EITHER
  ```

  In all of these cases, a user-provided value (`$1`) is used in a context where it will be parsed by the shell as code. In all of those cases, a value could thus run arbitrary commands.
- **This is always safe:**

  ```
  grep -e "$1" /var/log/*          ## ALWAYS DO THIS INSTEAD
  ```

  Again, this is *always* safe. Even if there's something like `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` inside your `$1`, the shell doesn't evaluate any of that content as syntax, so the values are inherently incapable of being parsed as code.

## Generating Shell Command Lines Safely

#### If forced to use `system()` or some equivalent

- **This is inherently unsafe:**

  ```c
  system("grep -e \"" + input + "\" /var/log/*")       /* DO NOT EVER DO THIS */
  system("grep -e '" + input + "' /var/log/*")  /* DO NOT EVER DO THIS EITHER */
  ```
- **This is inherently safe:**

  ```c
  setenv("logs_to_grep", input); /* IF YOU MUST USE system(), DO THIS INSTEAD */
  system("grep -e \"$logs_to_grep\" /var/log/*")
  ```

  Note how we didn't put the value inside of the string passed to a shell at all, but passed it out-of-band, in an environment variable (using a lower-case name, so it couldn't overwrite any of the environment variables with security-sensitive meaning to the operating system and supporting tools).

#### Generating Safe Command Lines From Another Shell Script

Let's say you need to run a command with untrusted input over SSH. `printf %q` can help:

```
printf -v args_q '%q ' "$@"
ssh somehost 'bash -s' <<EOF
command_with $args_q
EOF
```

Why the `bash -s`? To ensure your `args_str` is parsed by bash, as `printf %q` does not guarantee POSIX-safe output.

#### But The Better Option? Don't Invoke Extra Shells.

Instead of using `system()` or anything that invokes `sh -c`, use language-level facilities that directly use the `execve()` syscall to invoke your script. For example, in Python:

```py
# BAD/EVIL/INSECURE
subprocess.Popen('yourscript ' + arg, shell=True)  ## DO NOT EVER DO THIS

# GOOD/SECURE
subprocess.Popen(['yourscript', arg])              ## DO THIS INSTEAD.
```

## Don't Do Other Unsafe Things

- `xargs -I{} sh -c 'something_with {}'` -- because your placeholder, `{}`, substitutes into a value parsed by `sh` as code, it's parsed as code, not data. Don't do that.

  Instead, pass your data out-of-band: `xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'for arg; do something_with "$arg"; done' _` (if your data is inherently incapable of containing newline literals; if you can't prove that to be true, use NUL delimiters and `xargs -0` instead).
- `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'something_with {}' \;` -- same problem as with `xargs` above, with the same solution: `find . -exec sh -c 'for arg; do something_with "$arg"; done' _ {} +`
- Don't use `eval`, or `source`, or anything else that parses a non-constant string as code. Again, these values are all perfectly fine and safe *inside your data*; you simply shouldn't ever use them *in your code*.
- Don't make assumptions about filenames, except those that your operating system enforces itself. Don't use `ls` in scripts. Don't separate filenames with newlines -- use NULs instead.

Comment: Excellent writeup!