# F-Strings with Command Line in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, git-push

I wrote a small python function that executes a git push from Jupyter Notebook. Upon using an f-string with an input function within the
!git commit -m f'{msg}' it always includes the f from the f-string formatting. Is there a better way to format this script to get rid of the f?

This is what the commit messages look like on git

`f\\ trying to make git push more readable`

```
def git_push():
    msg = input('What is the commit message?\n')
    !git add .
    !git commit -m f'\\ {msg}'
    !git push
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest staying away from Jupyter's magic syntax on this one and sticking to standard Python.

Comment: Also, note that there are security problems here. A commit message of `Make $(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)' safe to handle` would not itself be safe to handle with this code, because the quotes inside the data would reverse the ones added in the format string.

Comment: (that specific example is assuming a UNIXy operating system, but the problem is not UNIX-family-specific).

Comment: What @CharlesDuffy say is true. From a security standpoint, this is very dangerous. There are many interactive resources available for learning `git`. If the goal is to teach students about `git`, teach them `git`. Trying to do so in Jupyter Notebook will confuse users as to how to do it and they will be dependent on Jupyter Notebook, which serves other purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was hoping to avoid having to slip between two programs jupyter notebook and terminal.  I don't intend to use it for more than just updating git. At this time, I am the only one in the repo, so hopefully, I will avoid using commands, as you mentioned. Is there a source code editor that includes shortcuts in a notebook-like format that you all would recommend?

Comment: Additionally, I am hoping to use inputs into python code in the future for automating file creation. Is there a way to remove the f?

Comment: If I used a conditional to scan the input for commands that look like or any part of 
```Make $(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'``` 
couldn't that also be an easy solution?

Comment: In general, trying to fix injection vulnerabilities by scanning for specific known-bad things is doomed to failure unless the set of possible known-bad-things is inherently limited. See [What are the possible list of Linux bash shell injection commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687976/what-are-the-possible-list-of-linux-bash-shell-injection-commands). (In this case it _is_ possible to safely escape your string using `shlex.quote()`, but that's not a search-for-specific-bad-things approach).

Comment: That said, it sounds like you don't have a reason to use the jupyter-specific `!foo arg1 arg2` format. Is there any reason you don't use the standard Python `subprocess.call(['foo', 'arg1', 'arg2'])` approach? It works just as well in Jupyter as it works anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you for the lead. It's definitely a slippery slope coding for bad things. I did some research on the subprocess module. It looks like this  [Interacting with GitHub using Python](https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2017/03/19/interacting-with-github-using-python/) article is something like what you suggested as a better approach. Hopefully, it's coded for Python3.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is a bad idea.
However, nobody pointed out your wrong premise: In the magic `! …` command, you did not (and cannot AFAICS) use f-strings. As the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) points out, [PEP-215](https://peps.python.org/pep-0215/) is used for string interpolation in this case.

Consider the following example:

```
def example(msg):
    !echo f'\\ {msg}'
    !echo '\\ {msg}'
    !echo {msg}
    # ---
    x = 1/3
    !echo {x:.3f}
    !echo {f"{x:.3f}"}

example('hello')
```

This prints

```
f\\ hello
\\ hello
hello
{x:.3f}
{f{x:.3f}}
```

As you can see,

- `msg` is still interpolated without the `f`
- `msg` is even interpolated without the quotes
- things that work with f-strings don't work here

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497069/passing-ipython-variables-as-arguments-to-bash-commands), for instance, gives more examples of the actual syntax.