# How to feed multi-line grep output to xargs with multiple parameters from each line

Tags: python, bash, csv

I have a CSV file to `grep` from, where the number of columns may vary, e.g.:

```
$ grep -v 'Coba' ETFs.csv | grep 'Sector'
CAPE,Ossiam Shiller Barclays Cape Europe Sector Value TR,EUPE,FWB
EUPB1,Ossiam Shiller Barclays Cape Global Sector Value,EUPB,FWB
```

For each output line of grep, I need to run a Python script and submit column #3 with the flag `-t` and column #2 with the flag `-n`. For simplicity's sake, let's assume the script prints submitted parameters. Thus, upon receiving the output above, the script should be executed two times like this:

```
script.py -t EUPE -n Ossiam Shiller Barclays Cape Europe Sector Value TR
script.py -t EUPB -n Ossiam Shiller Barclays Cape Global Sector Value
```

My problem is that `xargs` handles the entire `grep` output as one parameter. The expected behavior is to process input line-by-line, split the line content by coma and submit it to the script in any desired order. How to do that?

Example Python script:

```
import argparse, sys

aparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
aparser.add_argument('-t', '--ticker', required=True)
aparser.add_argument('-n', '--name')

args = aparser.parse_args()
print(f"START {sys.argv[0]} for {args.ticker} {args.name}: ", end='')
```

**UPDATE 23.3**

What currently works is to submit only one parameter as the ticker flag `-t`, since `-n` name flag is optional. Nevertheless, the real case scenario is to submit more than one flag at once, e.g., ETF ticker and name, screener, exchange, etc.

```
$ grep -v 'Coba' ETFs.csv | grep 'Sector' | cut -d ',' -f3 | xargs -I {} python script.py -t {}
```

as pointed out in the commentary, it can be expressed with `awk` too.

```
$ awk -F, '! /Coba/ && /Sector/ {print $3}' ETFs.csv | xargs -I {} python script.py -t {}
```

The solution suggested by @SHERLOCK actually looks logical. We extract different parts of the same input. However, the second parameter submission does not work, resulting in `argparse` usage reminder.

```
awk -F, '! /Coba/ && /Sector/ {printf "%s,%s\n", $3, $2}' ETFs.csv | xargs -t -I {} bash -c 'python script.py -t $(echo "{}" | awk -F "," "{print \$1}") -n $(echo "{}" | awk -F "," "{print \$2}")'
```

Harmful code injection like `rm -rf` should not be of concern here, as I always start by inspecting the CSV output and only then pipe it to the script.

Comment: xargs splits on words, not lines, unless you use `-d` or `-0` arguments. Make sure you're including enough code to let us see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Honestly, it's not clear to me why you'd mess with a shell wrapper instead of processing the CSV file in Python in the first place. It'd bypass the security problems that poorly-written shell is prone to (_really_, don't run any code telling you to use `xargs -I{} sh -c '...{}...'` -- I discuss that particular antipattern in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687976/what-are-the-possible-list-of-linux-bash-shell-injection-commands), and it'd also be much more efficient (`xargs -n 1` or `xargs -I{}` is running one subprocess per item)

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to stick with the original shell-wrapper approach, [edit] your question to ensure that you're providing a [mre] that shows us exactly how you used xargs in your original code; right now, there's no xargs in it at all; if you aren't showing us the _exact_ code that doesn't work (and _exactly how_ you determined that it "doesn't work" -- not just your conclusions but the symptoms from which they were surmised), we can't speak authoritatively to how and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, the python script is an external thing, I can only use it as is. In general, it provides all the necessary functionality. But the data comes on my end, so I need to prepare it before submission.

As for my commands with xargs, I didn't include it because it failed. Therefore, a detailed explanation of what needs to be done before feeding the script is provided:

Comment: > The expected behavior is to process input line-by-line, split the line content by coma and submit it to the script in any desired order.

Comment: Right, but failed code is _exactly what we want_. We're building a knowledge base of soluitons to technical problems; the code that failed, and _how_ it failed, is part of the problem. If we don't know exactly how you tried to use xargs, we can't conclusively say why it behaved the way it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop is a better choice than `xargs`:

```bash
while IFS=, read -r col3 col2 _ <&3; do
    python script.py -t "$col3" -n "$col2"
done 3< <(awk -F, '! /Coba/ && /Sector/ {printf "%s,%s\n", $3, $2}' ETFs.csv)
```

This way we're not starting a separate shell per line, but just have the same shell that was already running your script loop over awk's stdout from Python. Thus, both security issues and quoting bugs are addressed.

---

Some notes:

- Using file descriptor 3 instead of the default fd 0 (stdin) for the redirection leaves stdin free so `script.py` can use it for things like prompting the user without reading data from `ETFs.py` unintentionally.
- The `_` following `col2` causes subsequent fields to be discarded (well -- put into the variable `_`, which is conventional in scripts to use for junk intended to be ignored) rather than appended to the value in col2.
- See [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) to understand why the `while read ...;  done < <(awk ...)` idiom is used instead of `awk ... | while read ...; done`.
- If the set of lines that awk is being used to filter out isn't huge, you could just get rid of awk entirely and use bash for the filtering:

  ```bash
  while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 _ <&3; do
     [[ $col2 = *Coba* ]] && continue   # skip lines with Coba in description
     [[ $col2 = *Sector* ]] || continue # skip lines without Sector in description
     python script.py -t "$col3" -n "$col2"
  done 3<ETFs.csv
  ```
- The most obvious bug in the original xargs approach given in the question (besides the security issues which are described as addressed by human review) is missing quotes around the command substitutions -- `"$(...)"`, not just bare `$(...)`, prevents words in the resulting string from being split into separate arguments (and then expanded as globs based on filesystem contents in the current working directory). Because the descriptions of your ETFs in the second column contain spaces, that's critical for this data.

Comment: Double quotes in doubles quotes feel contra-intuitive, but it works.

Comment: Each `$()` starts a new quoting context. It's not "in" the original double quotes anymore. (This is one of the major advantages that modern command substitution syntax has over the backtick-based syntax it replaced; that old syntax was a nightmare to nest).

Comment: That said, I really do recommend using the `while read` approach given in this answer -- it's a whole lot more efficient than having xargs start a shell that forks off two subshells and runs two separate copies of awk for each and every line of data before even getting to the point of starting Python.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the '-d' flag with xargs to specify the delimiter as ',' and the '-I' flag to specify a placeholder for the input string. After which, you can use 'awk' to extract the desired columns from each line and pass them as arguments to the Python script.

Here's what you can do:

```
grep -v 'Coba' ETFs.csv | grep 'Sector' | xargs -d',' -I {} sh -c 'script.py -t $(echo "{}" | awk -F"," "{print \$3}") -n "$(echo "{}" | awk -F"," "{print \$2}")"'
```

This will split each input line by ',' then use awk to extract the third and second columns and pass them as arguments to script.py. The second column is enclosed in double quotes to handle cases where it contains spaces.

You may need to modify the command slightly depending on your shell and the exact format of your CSV file.

Comment: `xargs -I{} sh -c '...{}...'` is a serious security problem; it means that values can be parsed as code instead of data. It's much safer to pass your data out-of-band from your code by leaving out `-I` and letting xargs append content to the argument list (`$1`, `$2`, etc), then writing your code to check that argument list.

Comment: Consider what happens when your file has an ETF named `$(rm -rf ~)`; you don't want `echo "$(rm -rf ~)"` to run. Switching to single quotes doesn't help, because an ETF named `'$(rm -rf ~)'` will reverse them.

Comment: BTW, think about `awk '/Sector/ && ! /Cobra/'` instead of two different `grep`s. (Mind, I don't see why this isn't all _just one_ awk call in the first place).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : better yet, just make it `awk '/Cobra/ < /Sector/'`